# Classnot found exception while dealing with android admob Banner

Tags: android, admob, classnotfoundexception

I am getting this very annoying error in LogCat

```
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.vahzay.android.smstrove/com.vahzay.android.smstrove.ListMessages}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1179)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:491)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:252)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at com.vahzay.android.smstrove.ListMessages.onResume(ListMessages.java:650)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1159)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4553)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     ... 12 more
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:554)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
12-11 13:40:53.178: E/AndroidRuntime(4483):     ... 22 more
```

I have included the admob-sdk-android.jar through `order and import` from

```
properties-->android-->java Build Path.
```

Is there something else I need to deal with to add adds in my app? My Xml file has following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

<com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/> ...
```

Comment: add `admob-sdk-android.jar` file in your `libs` folder.

Comment: I have already added this in    {libs} folder but the result is same...

Comment: Are you sure it is in the `libs` folder? `lib` is different.

Comment: In my root directory there is only **libs** folder..Should there be a lib folder?

Comment: There should not be a `lib` folder.

Comment: I solved that problem as I was not adding GoogleAdMobAdsSdk.jar in my `libs` folder. As soon I copied it, all errors vanished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the problem by adding GoogleAdMobAdsSdk.jar in my project/libs folder.